# Qt - Insertar un QTableWidget en a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, datatable, interfaz-gráfica, qtablewidget

Quería insertar una tabla en otra tabla en una GUI en Qt. La idea es que cada celda de la tabla padre contenga una tabla hija. ¿Esto es posible?

Gracias y saludos!

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: tengo una tabla en la que inserto imágenes en las celdas, pero no sabría como insertar una nueva tabla en cada celda

Comment: ¿Y bajo que contexto es eso necesario? Me pica la curiosidad. Por otro lado, para hacerlo tendrás que usar delegados. Mira la documentación de [`QAbstractItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html)

Comment: Sería para mostrar datos de distinto tipo (que forman una estructura) en cada celda de la tabla. Cada celda de la tabla padre muestra un objeto y cada celda de la clase hijo muestra un campo de dicho objeto. No se si es la forma más correcta de hacerlo. Gracias!

Comment: Para eso tienes `QTreeView`, en los que puedes crear una vista en árbol con todos los nodos hijos que te de la gana. Piensa que una tabla ocupa muchísimo espacio en pantalla (cabeceras horizontales y verticales, celdas, scroll, ...) Te quedarías sin pantalla en un suspiro